# I want my form to be in the middle of my page not at the top center

Tags: html

i added my elements such as simple input fields and the code below doesn't put the form at the center rather it puts it at the top center. Please help me out. Thank you

This the code i use:

```html
<div align="center">
<form>
.
.
My elements
.
.
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: You should take a look at CSS. Here are some useful links to get you started: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS), [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/topics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put this css:

```css
div{
  display: block;
  width: 200px; //pick the width you want
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

In a html like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do when centering is refer to [this](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)  css tricks article.

Click the option to center vertically and horizontally and that will sort you out :)